# handling repeating xml elements in mule

Tags: mule

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <root xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">                                                                   
   <input>
    <rows>
     <example>
        <string>1</string>
        <string>345</string>
        <string>fg8</string>
        <string>8384</string>
     </example>
     <example>
        <string>2</string>
        <string>453</string>
        <string>8</string>
        <string>dsrsg</string>
     </example>
     <example>
        <string>3</string>
        <string>3456</string>
        <string>11</string>
        <string>grthy</string>
     </example>
     </rows>
   </input>
  </root>
```

Here i have to capture the each example tag and have to get the string values and insert into the db. Im trying to get the values by using xpath but no luck. Also tried by coverting to java object.
Please suggest me , how to handle this scenario.

sample code:

```
 <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration1" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <byte-array-to-object-transformer  mimeType="application/xml" doc:name="Byte Array to Object"/>
    <splitter expression="#[xpath3('/*:root/input/rows', payload, 'NODESET')]" doc:name="Splitter"/>
    <logger message="splitter : #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Comment: which version of mule did you used?

Comment: i am using mule server 3.8.3

Comment: Try to use dataweave to transform into a java object instead of xpath3 then use collection splitter or just splitter.

Comment: @RalphRimorin  Tried it too, but the xml has a duplicate element names(sting) and not forming a proper java collection object.

Comment: Here is the output of dataweave ::
       
        root={input={rows={example={string=grthy}}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@muleDev, try this Dataweave script:

[image]